# get the next outerHeight in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, dolor.</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis eligendi consectetur ad sit porro?</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt itaque architecto quae necessitatibus enim blanditiis dolores numquam libero.</li>
</ul>

<div id="size"></div>
```

CSS:

```
ul { width:250px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border:1px solid #999;  }
ul li { background:#ddd; padding:6px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; }
```

I have the first Height of the li, Now each 2 seconds I need to get the next height of the li, so I tried something like that, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
setInterval( function(){  
  var firstHeight = $('ul li').first.outerHeight();  
      $('#size').append( firstHeight.next() );          
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this produces the outcome you wanted.

I declared the start variable outside the function and inside the function used the outerHeight() and next() functions. hope this helps.

```
 var item = $('ul li').first();

a = setInterval( function(){ 
    height = item.outerHeight();  
    $('#size').append( height );
    item = item.next(); 
    if(item.length==0){
        console.log("stopped");
        clearInterval(a);
    }

}, 2000);
```

working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvuz4yn6/1/

edit: added interval stop when last item is reached

Comment: What does it mean item.length==0, it will never be 0, isn't it?

Comment: item.length returns the amount of elements found with your criteria. when you get passed the last element, you have no element therefore the elements matched is 0. here is the documentation(http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: oh.. sorry, I didn't mention something else, In my code it will never be 0 because I did something else that the list is running all the time...